# Importing a *random* csv file from a folder into pandas

Tags: pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I have a folder with several csv files, with file names between 100 and 400 (Eg. 142.csv, 278.csv etc). Not all the numbers between 100-400 are associated with a file, for example there is no 143.csv. I want to write a loop that imports 5 random files into separate dataframes in pandas instead of manually searching and typing out the file names over and over. Any ideas to get me started with this?

Comment: load all the filenames into an array. Randomly choose a name from that array and load?

Comment: Use `files =`[`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) and [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)`(files, 5)`

Comment: @QuangHoang, that is what I tried, and couldn't figure out a simple syntax error which was causing me issues. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisA, I'm not familiar with glob, I will look it up. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use glob and read all the csv files in the directory.

```
file = glob.glob('*.csv')
random_files=np.random.choice(file,5)
dataframes= []
for fp in random_files :
    dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(fp))
```

From this you can chose the random 5 files from directory and then read them seprately.
Hope I answer your question